# Infopath Form Load rules not working

Tags: infopath

I have publish a Infopath form (2010) into a SharePoint 2007 server library. I notice that the rules that I set on the Infopath form seem to be not working. When I open the Infopath form and select `form load` to inspect the rules that I set, I notice that some of them are no longer visible.

Please advise. (I was wondering if it is a different version that is causing the problem or Infopath rules for `form load` is limited to a number, say 5.?)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I notice that if I edit the Infopath form on Infopath 2007, it seems that the rules for the load form will be visible if created.

This look like a bug. Here are the steps below that will lead you to the bug:

Step 1: Open the infopath form in Infopath 2010 and create 6 rules for `Form Load` and Save it as a file.

Step 2: Open that infopath form that you created in Step 1 in InfoPath 2010 and go to the `Form Load` section. You will only see the first 5 rules. The 6th rules that you created for Step 1 will just "vanish". Now, close that infopath form.

Step 3: Open that infopath form that you created in step 1 in InfoPath 2007 and select Tools > Form Option. In the `Open and Save` category, click the `Rules` button and add a new rule in it and save it.

Step 4: Open that infopath form that you modify as describe in Step 3 in InfoPath 2010. That 6th rule will be visible.

Therefore, there might be a bug in InfoPath 2010 that restrict Rules to a max of 5 in Form Load and thus if anyone open that form in SharePoint, only the first 5 rules will be executed.

However, I would still need someone from the community to confirm my findings for the bug is true or false. Thanks.

Comment: I would have checked it if I understood why would one want 6+ rules with one action instaead of one rule with 6+ actions on Form Load?

Comment: Yes, definitely I wish to have one rule with 6+ actions but the problem is that I have 6+ different conditions which result in my creating 6+ different rules. In my case, each rule require one action each and so I can say that I just "hit the jackpot".